# Is it possible to A/B test web servers using a PHP redirect and sub domains without breaking all the SEO goodness?

Tags: seo, php, a-b-testing

We're trying to figure out if a certain type of web server architecture is better than our current web server. We need to A/B test these 2 boxes with live traffic to really get a sense of which one performs better on our internal KPIs. The hosts involved can't help with the A/B test. So naturally I'm looking to see if it's possible to roughly split the traffic 50:50 between the servers using PHP redirects and sub domains. For example:

- www.mydomain.com - (randomly redirects all requests to 1 of the following sub domains, maintaining url structure and query strings...)

  - www1.mydomain.com (original webserver config)
  - www2.mydomain.com (new webserver config)

We would need to run this test for at least a week or two to generate good stats. What I'm not sure about is whether the search engines would see this as bad and effect our rankings.

Answer (score 1):

A/B testing via PHP will not break your SEO as long as you aren't using any kind of SEO hacking "tricks".

Webpages around the web have all kind of different PHP scripts and companies like Google are pretty good at figuring out what is going on.

Webpage A: Has structured information and links.

Webpage B: Has (generally) the same structured information and links.

To indexing companies these two pages are the same but to your user one might be better(finding information, commenting, retention, etc) and finding out which (A or B) is the point.

Just keep an eye on your analytics platform and tag, comment, or mark any strange dips.

Comment: No tricks. Just want to test server hardware. Content will be identical (other than some JS tracking code differences).

So you don't think the URL changes will cause problems? www & www1 and www2?

Comment: @jnthnclrk Google's algorithm and others do not care about the www1 and www2. As long as your not redirecting to a known spam site or something really strange or out of the ordinary your sites SEO will be fine. The same kind of thing is used for website load balancing where different nodes are named www1-www20 and the loaded balancer redirects users to an under utilized node or a node at random. The key is having the same information on each node.

Comment: Sounds great. The only problem is @JVerstry in another answer seems to disagree with you.

Comment: @jnthnclrk what part of our answers disagree? I'd be happy to clarify.

Comment: You seem to be saying it's no big deal. Whereas JVerstry says this is a big change and will be considered duplicate content. I'd love to see some votes from others here.

Comment: @jnthnclrk Multiple sub-domains (www1-www20) will not hurt your SEO. Not having a canonical link element in your pages can hurt your SEO. Having a canonical link element is always a good idea. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element

Comment: Splitting a domain in multiple new domains will kill (I should say dilute) existing SEO benefits and rankings. Duplicate content on different URLs is extra competition for the same user queries in search results, unless canonicals are implemented.

Comment: Right, so you both do appear to differ on this...

Comment: There are situations where Google will automatically consider a domain name and a subdomain as one entity, but you should not rely on this, because your initial plan is to redirect to subdomains only.

Comment: TdotThomas, I already have canonical set to www, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

If the content and internal link structure is different between both servers (I am not talking about the presentation), bots will notice the changes and will likely increase their visits to your site.

They will be very confused if they are being served different content back and forth and this may trigger a manual review. Google wants to be sure about the content being served to users. If algorithms have doubts, they tend to remove sites from search results automatically too.

To avoid such issues, make sure that a given user is always served content from the same server, by setting a cookie for example. Keep in mind Google bots don't use cookies, but you can [detect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677419/how-to-detect-search-engine-bots-with-php) them and send them to the original config server.

If you do that, you will be SEO safe.

Comment: So the page visible content will be 100% the same as we only want to test server hardware in our A/B test. The only difference in the page source will be that www1 will have different Pingdom RUM code to www2. Other than that the pages should be exact copies. The most significant change, in my mind, is the URL structure.

Comment: If you change the URL structure, then this will be considered as a site structure change. Google indexes pages per their URL. It is a big change. Google will consider your content as duplicate content. It will not penalize you, but you may lose some rankings because of competition between your pages. You should set canonical links to avoid this issue.

Comment: So keep <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/" /> focused on www.?

Comment: If the new webserver has different URLs than original urls on the old server, then the pages served with the new URL should have a canonical link containing the original url. So page www2.example.com/newstructure/mypage.html should have a canonical link with www.example.com/oldstructure/mypage.html.

Comment: You should not have www.example.com/oldstructure/mypage.html redirected to www1.example.com/oldstructure/mypage.html and having a canonical pointing at www.example.com/oldstructure/mypage.html, because that is a loop Google won't like. It will create a mess.

Comment: The only structural change I need to make is on the subdomain. The rest of the URL will maintain the structure. I tried to explain that in the question...

Comment: www.example.com -> www1.example.com || www2.example.com

Comment: In that case, all your SEO benefit will be split between www1 and www2.

Comment: That doesn't sound too bad after all this will be a temporary test. Initially, you sounded as though this was a pretty heinous thing to do.

Comment: I still think it is a bad idea, because some people who played with similar splits and tests did not always recover all their rankings (or only after several weeks or months). If you traffic is business critical, you should avoid this loss by maintaining www.example.com and implementing www2.example.com only (instead of replacing www with www1). You have been warned lol

Comment: Ok so www -> www || www1 gives me better odds? Yes, the site is super business critical. But the hardware test is also super business critical. Lol.

Comment: Yes, much better odds because you are not forcing Google to replace all the www urls it has already indexed with www1 and www2 versions. If you revert to www later, it would be more confusing to Google again.

Comment: On second thoughts, because we're testing hardware, we will need 3 sites. www -> www1 || www2. This allows us to AB test the all important first few bytes on www1 and www2. Using just 2 sites/ subdomains might give www an unfair advantage.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider to use .htaccess to redirect Googlebot always to `www.`, and keep canonical urls to the www. version.

Redirect people with 302 redirections, obviously.

If it's not a good solution, maybe there's another road:
you can consider to not redirect all your traffic to `ww1.` or `ww2.` Keep 34% of your visitors on `www.`, then split the rest to ww1 and ww2 for 33% each.

You need more time to achieve statistical significance, but in that way you can keep a good amount of traffic on default and it would be more like an A/A/B test.